# DNS Error from ISP Server

Tags: dns, nslookup

I have a strange DNS error when attempting to access the domain rrrr.com. I have called to my ISP technical support, but they said they would call back and have not.

The domain is not accessible, but all the records and servers are correct.

```
nslookup rrrrr.com 167.206.10.179
Server:     167.206.10.179
Address:    167.206.10.179#53

** server can't find rrrrr.com: SERVFAIL
```

Where 167.206.10.178 and 167.206.10.179 are my ISP DNS servers.

Using OpenDNS:

```
nslookup rrrrr.com
Server:     208.67.222.222
Address:    208.67.222.222#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   rrrrrr.com
Address: 54.88.87.161
```

Is there any way that I can debug this? It has been going on several days.

Comment: My ISP and Google DNS also can't find it. The domain registration was changed on Oct 4, did you move it to new nameservers on that date?

Comment: Also, can you post the IP and ISP of the DNS where you get the SERVFAIL?

Comment: I got it from Google DNS 8.8.8.8 and Comcast 75.75.75.75.

Comment: And where did you see written Oct-8?

Comment: `whois fitango.com` says: `Updated Date: 04-oct-2014`

Comment: Any idea how to find where they got their information?

Answer (score 0):

The question is not resolved absolutely, but the problem appears to be with the GoDaddy DNS Servers. The problem appeared to be continuously growing and their technical support denied that anything was wrong - "appears to be a localized issue with some ISPs".

[image]

So I added for now backup DNS with Namecheap.com

[image]

Also useful is this post:

http://rscott.org/dns/GoDaddy_Selective_DNS_Blackouts.htm